# How to allowonly the child page to be active and diable the parent page, just like how popups work

Tags: javascript

I want to make my page work like popups, when the window is open then the parent page must not be active

I pasted the code below

```
window.open('FrameValidation.aspx?cid="' + newElementId + '"&serviceDate="' + serviceDate + '"', 'google', ' menubar,resizable,dependent,status,top=150,width=630px,height=570px, top=0, left=960');
```

the window does popup but now the parent window is still accessible

Comment: add css to style it like block and disable mouse events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created one demo, you can try it will be helpful for you to achieve this requirement.

**Parent Page**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
   background:#fff;
}
.popup-container {
    position: absolute;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

    font-size: 50px;
    user-select: none;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}
button.refresh-button {
    background: #2991d6;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5 20px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var popupWindow=null;
function child_open()
{ 
   $(".popup").css("display","block");
    popupWindow =window.open('child.html',"_blank");
    console.log(popupWindow);
}
$(document).delegate(".refresh-button","click",function(){
    location.reload();
    popupWindow.close()
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).focus(function(){
        if(popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed)
        {
            popupWindow.location.href = "child.html";
            popupWindow.focus();
        }       
        else 
        {
            $(window).focus();
            location.reload();
            $('body').css("opacity","1");
            $('body').css("background","#fff");
        } 
    });
    var timer = setInterval(function() {   
        if(popupWindow && popupWindow.closed) {  
            clearInterval(timer);  
            location.reload(); 
        }  
    }, 500);
});

function parent_disable() {
    if(popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed)
    {
        popupWindow.focus();    
    } else {
        $('body').css("opacity","1");
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onfocus="parent_disable();" onclick="parent_disable();">
    <a href="javascript:child_open()">Click me</a>
    <div class="popup" style="display:none">
    <div class="popup-container" >
      <div class="popup-content">
         <h5>Operation in progress...</h5>
         <button type="button" class="refresh-button">Refresh</button>
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

**Child Page**

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(window).blur(function(){
        window.focus();
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        window.focus(); 
    });
</script>
<body >
I am child
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty "overlay" div at a DOM level above the "parent" page content and at the same DOM level as the modal. Position this div fixed (or absolute) and size it to cover the entire page. Hide it when no modal is active and display it when the modal is active. When this overlay div is displayed, it serves as a barrier to the underlying content so whatever the user tries to do (click links, select text, etc) to the underlying parent page is effectively blocked. Set the z-index of the overlay element to a number lower than that of the modal element, so the overlay is beneath the modal. Play with the opacity of the overlay element to make the parent page content less or more opaque.

There are other approaches. This one is the simplest I know of and covers all the edge cases.